# how to launch 10 coroutines in for loop and wait until all of them finish?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I need to fill list of objects from DB. And before passing value to itemes I want all of them to finish. Is here any short way calling await() for each item to wait. I want to make clean code, May be some design pattern or trick?

```
    for (x in 0..10) {
        launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                list.add(repository.getLastGame(x) ?: MutableLiveData<Task>(Task(cabinId = x)))
            }

        }

    }
    items.value = list
```

Comment: 1) Is your repository a singleton? 2) where do you launch this coroutine? In ViewModel?

Comment: yes it singleton and it inside ViewModel

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
coroutineScope { // limits the scope of concurrency
    (0..10).map { // is a shorter way to write IntRange(0, 10)
        async(Dispatchers.IO) { // async means "concurrently", context goes here
            list.add(repository.getLastGame(x) ?: MutableLiveData<Task>(Task(cabinId = x)))
        }
    }.awaitAll() // waits all of them
} // if any task crashes -- this scope ends with exception
```

Answer (score 4):

```
IntRange( 0, 10 ).map {
    async {
       // Logic
    }
}.forEach {
    it.await()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, similar to the others, for use with firestore snapshots.

---

```
scope.launch {
    val annualReports = snapshots.map { snapshot ->
        return@map async {
                AnnualReport(
                    year = snapshot.id,
                    reports = getTransactionReportsForYear(snapshot.id) // This is a suspended function
                )
        }
    }.awaitAll()
}
```

---

**Returns:**

```
listOf(AnnualReport(...), AnnualReport(...))
```

Answer (score 0):

and then `+semaphore`

```
val semaphore = Semaphore(5)

coroutineScope {
    list.map {

        async {
            semaphore.acquire()
            
            // logic(it)
            
            semaphore.release()
        }
    }.awaitAll()
}
```